# How to setup microphone with Azure Speech Services C# SDK on Raspberry Pi 4

Tags: c#, .net-core, raspberry-pi, speech-recognition, azure-speech

I am playing around creating a home assistant using Raspberry Pi 4 and Azure speech services. I have a keyword model setup and listen for the keyword using the following code.

```
using AudioConfig audioConfig = AudioConfig.FromDefaultMicrophoneInput();
using var keywordRecognizer = new KeywordRecognizer(audioConfig);
await keywordRecognizer.RecognizeOnceAsync(keyword);
```

This works flawlessly when running on my windows 10 laptop (using the laptop microphone) inside VS 2022.

The microphone I am using with the raspberry pi is the Respeaker 4-mic array.

When I deploy it to the raspberry pi it doesn't seem to pick up the microphone. I have edited etc/asound.conf to ensure the microphone I want to use is set as the default. My microphone uses card 1 and is device 0. I have tested that the microphone does work use Audacity.

I have even swapped the .FromDefaultMicrophoneInput to:

```
using AudioConfig audioConfig = AudioConfig.FromMicrophoneInput("hw:CARD=1,DEV=0");
```

or

```
using AudioConfig audioConfig = AudioConfig.FromMicrophoneInput("hw:1,0");
```

following azures documentation: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/azure/cognitive-services/speech-service/how-to-select-audio-input-devices

The two above crash with the error: SPXERR_MIC_NOT_AVAILABLE. This makes me believe that the microphone isn't being found.

Any help on how I can get the Azure SDK to use the microphone on the Raspberry Pi for Keyword recognition would be greatly appriciated.

Many thanks

EDIT: I have tried a USB microphone and this does work. It seems to an issue around using a microphone connected via the GPIO pins?

Answer (score 0):

Installation of the ALSA libraries help to solve the SPXERR_MIC_NOT_AVAILABLE issue on my RPi 3.

```
sudo apt-get install gcc libasound2 libasound2-dev alsa-utils
```

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion, I have just tried this and my Pi 4 already has the latest version installed. So it can't be this. It just doesn't seem to pick the mic up.

Comment: It doesn't actually throw the 'SPXERR_MIC_NOT_AVAILABLE' error. It just doesn't pick up my voice from the mic.